# KeDei 6.3 Touch Screen stops working after upgrade

Tags: display, touchscreen, screen

I've recently bought [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5-TFT-LCD-Touch-Screen-Module-320-480-RGB-Display-Board-For-Raspberry-Pi-3/381182260459?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) display module for my Raspberry Pi 3.
It's the **version 6.3**. I followed the installation steps that I found on Google, so I burned `rpi_35_v6.3_jessie8_kernel_4_4_50` (that I found on [KeDei website](http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html)) to my SD card and booted from it. Everything works fine until I run `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.

After that on the next restart the display doesn't work, only shows blank white screen.
After some search I found [this](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/issues/10) article and realized I have to run `sudo apt-mark hold raspberrypi-bootloader` before the upgrade to exclude it from the upgrade process. But still doesn't work.
Is there a way to upgrade and keep the screen working?

This is the display I have (but ver 6.3)
[image]

Comment: Ask the supplier for a proper driver which doesn't involve a custom kernel (the idea of customising kernels has been obsolete for years).

Comment: What if they say it's the only way to use their display? No way to use it without outdated softwares and kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, in the sense that it will tell you how to "fix" your system, but will explain why it failed, and may help you recover.

If you have a backup image, restore this. (It is prudent to make a backup on ANY system before upgrading.)

The packages which caused problems are:-

```
Package: raspberrypi-bootloader
Description: Raspberry Pi bootloader
 This package contains the Raspberry Pi firmware and bootloader.

Package: raspberrypi-kernel
Description: Raspberry Pi bootloader
 This package contains the Raspberry Pi Linux kernel.
```

In addition to the kernel, these install matching drivers and firmware in `/lib/modules/`
These will be in a directory matching the kernel e.g. `4.9.59+/  4.9.59-v7+/`

Current packages delete the old modules (older versions just added newer modules, which filled up the SD Card).

You will need to obtain the modules which match the kernel, any you may be able to find in http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspberrypi-firmware/

Raspbian moved to kernel 4.9 in about May.

If you have to use an old kernel, you should not update raspberrypi-bootloader or raspberrypi-kernel. Jessie is no longer supported, so there are unlikely to be updates, other than security fixes, and you will be unable to use current versions `Stretch`